# How is memory allocated in this program?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, printf

i was messing around with pointers in C and i came across something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char *str2 = "Heyya";
    printf("%d %d %s\n", &str2, str2, str2);
    return 0;
}
```

the program ran successfully and gave output

**6422300 4214884 Heyya**

what I didn't understand is that how come the program printed "Heyya" without using * operator in the second "str2"(the one that is putting value to %s) in the printf function

PS when I run the same with *str2 it gives a segmentation fault

can anyone explain what is happening in the memory?

Comment: For format specifier `%s`, `printf` expects an address to `char`.  Dereferencing a pointer to `char` would result in a `char` value (i.e. `*str2` would result in `'H'`).  A segmentation fault occurs because `'H'` is not a valid address.

Comment: Printing `&str2` and `str2` using the `%d` format gives undefined behaviour, since neither `&str2` not `str2` are of type `int`, and `%d` tells `printf()` to assume they are.   The reason `str2` is printed using `%s` is because `%s` means that the argument is the address of the first character in a nul (zero) terminated string - which is the case.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756).

Answer (score 3):

`str2` is a pointer to a character-array which is a literal constant located in the code segment.  It is not "allocated."  It is simply part of the program's object-code.

Your `printf()` call now prints the following three things:

1. The address of the `str2` pointer variable itself, which is `6422300`.
2. The address of the character array in the code segment, pointed-to by the pointer at `6422300`, which is `4214884`.
3. The bytes that are located at address `4214884`, presented as a string.

Comment: Can you address segmentation fault?

Comment: Actually, `str2` is a pointer to the first character in an array.   The string literal initialiser means that `str2` points to the first character of a statically allocated array.   `str2` is not a pointer to an array

Answer (score 3):

For starters this call

```
printf("%d %d %s\n", &str2, str2, str2);
```

invokes undefined behavior because there are used incorrect conversion formats for pointers.

A correct call can look like

```
printf("%p %p %s\n", ( void * )&str2, ( void * )str2, str2);
```

As for the output then the expression `&str2` gives the address of the local variable `str2`. The expression `str2` gives the address of the first character of the string literal `"Heyya"` that has the static storage location.

If to use the above expression with the conversion format `%p` then the address will be outputted. If to use the above expression with the conversion format `%s` then the string first character of which pointed to by the expression str2 will be outputted.

You should understand that the address of the variable str2 itself is different from the address of the string literal pointed to by the variable. That is the expression &str2 yields the address of the variable itself. The expression str2 yields the value stored in the variable that in turn is the address of the first character of the string literal.

As for your question

> How is memory allocated in this program?

then in this declaration

```
char *str2 = "Heyya";
```

there is created a string literal `"Heyya"` with the static storage duration and that has the type `char[6]` (in C++ it has the type `const char[6]`) and a local variable `str2` with the automatic storage duration that is initialized by the address of the first character of the string literal.

Comment: The `(void *)` casts are unnecessary and may suppress warnings on some real errors.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Without the cast some compilers issue errors.

Comment: Not if they're to spec. If a function declares an argument type of `void*` (as printf implies with %p), then any pointer type can be passed, but if you tried to pass, say, an int, it would warn (which is good). If it warns you when passing an `int*`, then your compiler is broken (or perhaps it's set to expect C++ or a different version of C?)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker www,ideone.com, language C99, the program #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
 int x = 10;
 
 printf( "%p\n", &x );
 
 return 0;
}
 the compilation error prog.c:7:12: error: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]

Comment: I believe you, I'm just saying it's not supposed to do that, and there's a good reason it's not supposed to do that. I'd be curious as to what exact compiler and settings are used by ideaone.

Answer (score 3):

str2 is a pointer to a location in the memory where "Heyya" was stored. 
printf("%s", strpointer) will print the string pointed to by strpointer, until it reaches null terminator, which is what makes it a string. If you add '*' before str2, it will print only the value of the address str2 points at, which is "H". That's happening because '*p' is not a pointer, but it's the actual value of the address of p, but 'p' is a pointer and printf will print the string from the address of which p points to, untill Null Terminator.

Comment: Nitpick: `NUL` is `(char)0` and `NULL` is (probably) `(void *)0`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a function that let you print something from values given as supplementary arguments. *something*  means some representation from the value.

For instance:

`%d` takes the corresponding value and write it as a decimal number. You gave first `&str2`  which is the address of the pointer `str2`. Second you gave `str2` which is the value stored in `str2`, the address of a C-string. Note, that pointers must be print with `%p` not `%d`, but that is almost the same reasoning.

`%s` is more subtle as it takes an address where a C-string must be stored and print every characters of that C-string.